# How do I properly toggle between divs on a web form using this Javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, css, function, display

I am attempting to toggle display between two divs. The first contains a drop-down menu of existing sales representatives. The second contains a text input field to add a new sales representative. I want to prevent the user from seeing both divs at once. I want neither div to display when the page is first loaded.

Working properly:

1. Neither div displays at first.
2. Further, the div with ID="repIfChoose" displays when I click the radio button next to "Choose".

Not working properly:

1. The div with ID="repIfAdd" does not display when I click the radio button next to "Add".
2. Once the div with ID="repIfChoose" is first displayed, nothing happens when I alternate between the radio buttons afterward (meaning the repIfChoose div is not hidden and the repIfAdd div is not displayed.)

I know that there may be simpler solutions in JQuery, but I would prefer to accomplish this in vanilla Javascript. Can someone help me solve the two errors above and any other mistakes you might notice? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <!--Radio button to switch between choose and add sales representative (choose default)-->
  Choose <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="chooseInput" name="repRadio">
  <br><br> Add <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="addInput" name="repRadio">

  <div class="form-group" id="repIfChoose" style="display:none">
    <label>Choose Sales Representative</label>
    <select name="SalesRep">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Sales Representative</option>
      <option value="">Adam</option>
      <option value="">Bill</option>
      <option value="">Carl</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="repIfAdd" style="display:none">
    <label>Add Sales Representative</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Alex Branson" name="SalesRep">
  </div>

  <script>
    function repVisible() {
      if (document.getElementById('chooseInput').checked) {
        document.getElementById('repIfChoose').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('repifAdd').style.display = 'none';
      }
      if (document.getElementById('addInput').checked) {
        document.getElementByID('repIfChoose').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementByID('repIfAdd').style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getElementById()` had a few capitals D's; moreover, you id names had case problems as well.  Otherwise works:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qswkyLp/

Make sure to use developer console in your browser to debug code, easy to get to using F12 on PC, for most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You have bad typos... fix those and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <!--Radio button to switch between choose and add sales representative (choose default)-->
    Choose <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="chooseInput" name="repRadio">
    <br><br>
    Add <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="addInput" name="repRadio">

    <div class="form-group" id="repIfChoose" style="display:none">
        <label>Choose Sales Representative</label>
        <select name="SalesRep">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Sales Representative</option>                         
            <option value="">Adam</option>
            <option value="">Bill</option>
            <option value="">Carl</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="repIfAdd" style="display:none">
        <label>Add Sales Representative</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Alex Branson" name="SalesRep">
    </div>              

    <script>    
        function repVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('chooseInput').checked) {
                document.getElementById('repIfChoose').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('repIfAdd').style.display = 'none';
            }
            if  (document.getElementById('addInput').checked){ 
                document.getElementById('repIfChoose').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('repIfAdd').style.display = 'block';
            }   
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind pointing out the typos in your answer for future users to see?

Comment: I'd actually recommend deleting the question... It's such a common bug it's not really helpful to others.

Comment: @Ben Russell, if you inspect your code with your browser's developer tools, you will see helpful errors in the console that point out to us pretty quickly that you have typos like `.getElementByID` instead of `.getElementById`.

Comment: Yes... zbnrg is dead right. You should almost always have the console open when you're debugging.

Comment: Thank you, John Cullen and zbnrg. I'll do so in the future. Apologies for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, make below changes to fix syntax and typo errors

1. document.getElementById has been used with wrong case like getElementBy**ID**
2. id name should be used with same name as it is case sensitive - should be repIfAdd instead of **repifAdd**

```js
        function repVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('chooseInput').checked) {
                document.getElementById('repIfChoose').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('repIfAdd').style.display = 'none';
            }
            if (document.getElementById('addInput').checked){ 
                document.getElementById('repIfChoose').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('repIfAdd').style.display = 'block';
            }   
        }
```

```html
<head></head>
<body>

    <!--Radio button to switch between choose and add sales representative (choose default)-->
    Choose <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="chooseInput" name="repRadio">
    <br><br>
    Add <input type="radio" onclick="repVisible();" id="addInput" name="repRadio">

    <div class="form-group" id="repIfChoose" style="display:none">
        <label>Choose Sales Representative</label>
        <select name="SalesRep">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Sales Representative</option>                         
            <option value="">Adam</option>
            <option value="">Bill</option>
            <option value="">Carl</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="repIfAdd" style="display:none">
        <label>Add Sales Representative</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Alex Branson" name="SalesRep">
    </div>              



</body>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MGbPpv